# Increasing storage space with On-Premises SharePoint

Tags: 2013

I am using On-Premises SharePoint and I do not have access to the physical device that stores the data of the SharePoint site. I have contacted the people who are meant to help me with this, but it is a large company and they are essentially ignoring me. Is there any way I can increase the storage on my SharePoint site? Even if it's artificial (e.g. points to another storage area wherein I have uploaded files).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Site storage and resources allotment is completely controlled by SharePoint Admin Team. You can ask them to run below powershell script to increase storage quota for your site

```
$site=Get-SPSite -Identity "http://your_sp_domain/sites/your_site"
Set-SPSite -Identity $site -MaxSize 10GB -WarningSize 9.50GB
```

Answer (score 3):

No, storage is controlled by your IT department.